# Portable AC Drawing 0.33 Amps Trips 15 Amp Circuit Breaker?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

After about 5 min. my portable AC rated at 11.4 Amps trips the 15 Amp circuit breaker. I put a Kill-a-Watt meter on it and it was only drawing 0.33 Amps at time of the tripping.
Only other running elec. object tied in to the breaker is 'smoke alarm'.
Anyone have a fix or cause?

Comment: Does the breaker in question have a TEST button on it?

Comment: No test button. 1987 breaker.

Comment: What make and model is the breaker in question?

Comment: Bryant Bro looks like 80230-230

Comment: Can you post photos of the breaker in question please?

Comment: the 15 amp only has markings Olili

Comment: Sorry don't have working camera or cell phone.

Comment: I can get a picture of it noon EST tomorrow ... will that work?

Comment: I'm skeptical about 0.33 A - at 120V (portables are typically 120V in the US, not 240V) that's all of 40W - not much power.

Comment: @baborn -- yeah, that's fine

Comment: What other appliances are on the same circuit? Also, as stated by others, 0.33 A for the AC is unlikely.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I suspect that his meter took the reading when the A/C's compressor was not running; fan only might pull that amount. He needs to take another reading, preferably with a known good clamp-on meter, when the unit is running in maximum cooling.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with others .33a no way for even the smallest ac units. At 5 minutes I believe the circuit is being overloaded.

Most breakers for residential use are inverse time breakers. A 15 amp breaker loaded at 15.5 amps may not trip for a 1/2 hour push it to 16 amps and it will trip much quicker possibly 5 minutes.

I would check the load on that breaker with a clamp meter and would expect more than 15 amps. If the load is less than 15 the breaker is defective and needs to be replaced.

Comment: I want to thank everyone for your answers. I now believe that the problem is with the portable ac unit. I moved it to room #3 and it tripped that rooms breaker.